# pytest-cov get automation coverage from remote server

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py

I'm using py.test for REST API automation using python request library.

How to get coverage using pytest-cov tool. I'm running the automation on build server and code is executed in application server.

Answer (score 3):

The usual coverage tools are built for the much more common case of the measured code being run inside the same process as the test runner.  You not only are running in a different process, but a different machine.

You can use coverage.py directly on the remote machine when you start the process running the code under test.  How you would do that depends on how you start that process today.  The simple rule of thumb is that wherever you had been saying, "python my_prog.py", you can say, "coverage run my_prog.py".

Answer (score 0):

When you run the `py.test` command to kick off your tests, you can simply add the `pytest-cov` arguments to the command.

For example:

```
py.test --cov mycode --cov-report html  # plus other py.test arguments
```

Replace `mycode` with the name of the package or module containing your code. This tells the coverage plug-in to report coverage stats specifically on that code.

That's the simplest way to run `py.test`. You can make things a little more sophisticated by adding a [`.coveragerc` file](http://coverage.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html). Also check `py.test --help` for more information.

Comment: My application code is in the remote server and automation scripts are running in build server. I tried this but didn't get any application coverage.

Comment: What output do you get? How are you executing the scripts?

Comment: I executed the command you have mentioned

py.test --cov mycode --cov-report html

Output: Coverage.py warning: Module mycode was never imported.
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected

Please note: My application code is in remote server

Comment: I see what you mean now. If the code is _only_ on a remote server, and you don't actually have a copy of it locally then it is not possible to gather code coverage statistics. That's not how code coverage works. You need to have the application code and the test code on on the same machine. If you need to exercise the API and get code coverage, try using webtest: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WebTest.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Will try this out and let you know if it works!!